# зачем нужен synchronized в этом коде?

Tags: java, android, android-room

В туториале по андроид встетил такой код:
(Это туториал про создание базы данных Room и т.д)

```
@Database(entities = {Word.class}, version = 1, exportSchema = false)
public abstract class WordRoomDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

   public abstract WordDao wordDao();
   private static WordRoomDatabase INSTANCE;

   static WordRoomDatabase getDatabase(final Context context) {
       if (INSTANCE == null) {
           synchronized (WordRoomDatabase.class) {
               if (INSTANCE == null) {
                   INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                           WordRoomDatabase.class, "word_database")
                             // Wipes and rebuilds instead of migrating 
                             // if no Migration object.
                            // Migration is not part of this practical.
                           .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                           .build();                
               }
           }
       }
       return INSTANCE;
   }
}
```

Так вот не пойму для чего нужен synchronized ? и почему в параметры synchronized передаем класс ?

Comment: `private static volatile WordRoomDatabase INSTANCE` должно быть

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это паранойя, чисто технически, без этого `synchronized` 2 потока могут успеть пройти поверку

> `if (INSTANCE == null)`

И в таком случае будет создано 2 экземпляра, в каждом потоке свой.

Вот [статья на хабре](https://m.habr.com/ru/post/129494/), где сравнивают прелести синглтонов

Comment: А откуда берутся эти 2 потока ? Я например создаю объект этого класса в MainActivity и все.!

Comment: @Rarity7- поэтому я и написал что это паранойя у автора кода, он предполагал что такое может быть

Comment: А чтобы был 2 поток его же нужно только вручную создать ?

Comment: @Rarity7- я вообще не знаю тонкостей андроида, а так да - вручную